# On the same page, an inline SVG scales but an SVG embedded as an <img> doesn't - why not?

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG which I would like to use frequently across a new site.

Consequently, rather than writing the SVG inline on many pages, it seems to make sense to include the SVG on each page as a cacheable `<img>`, which, after the first download, will be retrievable from the browser cache.

The SVG I am calling via `<img>` is identical to what I would otherwise write inline - but where the inline SVG scales respective to browser width, the SVG called by `<img>` does not.

What do I need to do, to ensure the SVG called by `<img>` scales up and down in exactly the same way as if it were included inline?

**Example:**

```css
.handsoffhri-campaign-logo {
width: 80.5vw;
height: 12vw;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

pre, p pre {
display: inline;
}
```

```html
<p>Expand this window to <em>Full Page</em> and then narrow and widen the browser viewport to see how the two SVGs behave differently (though they are identical). How can I get the SVG called by <b>&lt;img&gt;</b> to scale up and down like the inline SVG?</p>

<h2>SVG called by <pre>&lt;img&gt;</pre></h2>
<img class="handsoffhri-campaign-logo" src="http://handsoffnhs.org/.assets/theme/elements/handsoffhri-logo.svg" alt="" />



<h2>SVG Inline</h2>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     viewbox="0 0 805 120">

<defs>

<filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0">
<feOffset result="offOut" dx="2" dy="2" />
<feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
<feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" stdDeviation="2" />
<feBlend in="SourceGraphic" mode="normal" />
</filter>

<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[

svg {
font-family: arial;
font-size: 84px;
font-weight: 900;
text-transform: uppercase;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

text, rect, path {
fill: rgb(0, 75, 165);
stroke: rgb(30, 40, 90);
stroke-width: 1;
}

rect + text {
fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

a:nth-of-type(2) rect {
stroke: none;
fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

path {
transform: translate(414px, 12px);
}


]]></style>
</defs>

<a xlink:href="http://handsoffhri.org/"><text x="0" y="70" filter="url(#shadow)">#Hands</text><rect x="396" y="0" width="200" height="80" /><text x="406" y="70">Off</text><text x="603" y="70" filter="url(#shadow)">HRI</text></a>

<a xlink:href="http://handsoffnhs.org/">
<rect x="426" y="20" width="30" height="40" />
<path d="M 17.923077,46.076923 C 14.343392,42.497239 14.27418,40.818155 17.53034,36.54911 19.670795,33.742828 19.964561,32.558959 19.43687,28.865832 19.093774,26.464624 18.091959,22.925 17.210613,21 15.473393,17.205632 14.946739,8.8090066 16.395225,8 c 0.492374,-0.275 1.522812,1.75 2.289861,4.5 0.76705,2.75 1.785893,5.9 2.264097,7 0.478204,1.1 1.121144,2.7875 1.428755,3.75 0.388325,1.215052 1.601353,1.75 3.968232,1.75 1.874918,0 3.94672,0.647984 4.604006,1.439966 0.657286,0.791981 2.129739,1.579481 3.272118,1.75 3.300549,0.492661 6.095959,4.949339 4.942528,7.879795 C 38.638723,37.406393 37.617787,40.525 36.896075,43 c -1.470078,5.04141 -2.354638,5.96259 -5.746769,5.984687 -2.184572,0.01423 -2.312807,-0.285031 -1.814586,-4.234687 0.29486,-2.3375 0.828492,-5.625597 1.18585,-7.306882 0.910327,-4.282879 -1.674633,-6.518656 -4.539328,-3.926143 -2.445773,2.213395 -2.522575,5.352525 -0.231242,9.451617 1.687087,3.018122 1.680216,3.182812 -0.19113,4.581039 -2.817812,2.105407 -4.353952,1.809133 -7.635793,-1.472708 z M 5.9073963,33.25 2.6076082,29.5 5.0157824,29.152671 C 7.7278899,28.761505 11,32.019342 11,35.110784 11,37.937782 9.573836,37.416676 5.9073963,33.25 Z M 41.007272,27 c 0.549073,-1.375 1.491079,-3.7375 2.093346,-5.25 0.602268,-1.5125 1.726011,-2.75 2.497207,-2.75 2.311553,0 1.576924,2.264983 -2.108223,6.5 -2.678238,3.077864 -3.250499,3.423665 -2.48233,1.5 z m -8.000683,-3.75 c 0.0036,-0.9625 0.900659,-3.1 1.993411,-4.75 1.092752,-1.65 1.989787,-4.4074 1.993411,-6.127555 0.0073,-3.4695992 2.322706,-6.2880071 3.543292,-4.3130587 0.626634,1.0139159 -1.08136,7.8982867 -3.644702,14.6906137 -1.001533,2.653854 -3.894924,3.026194 -3.885412,0.5 z m -6.936221,-3.118517 c -0.55,-1.027684 -0.689818,-2.1787 -0.310706,-2.557811 0.379112,-0.379112 0.559103,-3.58828 0.39998,-7.131483 C 25.922072,5.152178 26.148965,4 27.42827,4 c 1.304453,0 1.537588,1.4643706 1.432844,9 -0.123753,8.903267 -0.849702,10.758358 -2.790746,7.131483 z" id="path3690" />
</a>

</svg>
```

Comment: standalone SVG is case sensitive, html (and therefore SVG embedded in html) is not. The attribute you've written as viewbox is correctly written as view**B**ox

Comment: Wow. Unbelievable. Thank you so much. Please add this as an answer and I will accept. Many thanks, @RobertLongson - you have saved me many more hours of hair-pulling.

Comment: I have checked all my other SVGs - every single one of them has `viewBox`. I have genuinely no idea how this slipped under the radar. Many thanks again.

Comment: Typos are off-topic as Q&A. I voted to close the question as such. I don't think I should vote to close and answer.